# Converting ResultSet data to Pie Chart(Google charts) format

Tags: java, json, jdbc, charts, google-visualization

The output from resultset from JDBC is :

[image: OUTPUT in SqlWorkbench]

I need to convert it into:

A Stringbuffer named **data** that holds

```
         [
          ['Tiles', 'Hours per Day'],
          ['Cabs tile',     1375],
          ['recharge tile',      3377],
          ['deals tile',  1603],
          ['jobs tile', 437],
          ['education tile',    247],
          ['shopping tile',    433],
          ['household tile',    220]
        ]
```

I have tried using :

```
    public static StringBuffer data= new StringBuffer();
ResultSet rs //contains data in it.
ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();

         String col1 = rsmd.getColumnName(1);
         String col2 = rsmd.getColumnName(2);
         String col3 = rsmd.getColumnName(3);
         String col4 = rsmd.getColumnName(4);
         String col5 = rsmd.getColumnName(5);
         String col6 = rsmd.getColumnName(6);
         String col7 = rsmd.getColumnName(7);
         String col8 = rsmd.getColumnName(8);
         String col9 = rsmd.getColumnName(9);
         String col10 = rsmd.getColumnName(10);


         data.append("[ ['Tiles', 'Hours per Day'],");

        String formatStr = "%n['%s','%s'],";

         while(rs.next()){

            int total_cols = rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount();
            data.append((String.format(formatStr, col4, rs.getString(col4))));//This line is incorrect
            }
data.append("]");
```

Note that *the data is taken from 4th column of the ResultSet as the same is required to draw pie chart*,

Basically, the data from resultset is needed to be extracted columnwise and there is only one column in the resultSet

Comment: Simply write a loop to iterate over the required columns.

Comment: @qqilihq, can you elaborate more with code?

Answer (score 0):

your trying to convert your result set to a Json string. So it can be easily done  using  [JSON Object](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/json/json_java_example.htm) in java.

refer the code

```
.....
   JSONArray jsonArray0 = new JSONArray();

        while(rs.next()){
            JSONArray jasub = new JSONArray();
            jasub.add(col4);
            jasub.add(rs.getString(col4));

            jsonArray0.add(jasub);

        }


    System.out.println(jsonArray0.toJSONString());
```

Comment: Yes, You are correct,can you elaborate more with code

Answer (score 0):

Use a loop like this to iterate over the columns in your result row:

```
ResultSetMetaData metaData = resultSet.getMetaData();
int numColumns = metaData.getColumnCount();
for (int i = 1; i <= numColumns; i++) { // columns are one-indexed
    String columnName = metaData.getColumnLabel(i);
    String value = resultSet.getString(i);
    // …
}
```